# How can I send random notifications via Workmanager periodically

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I am able to send periodically notifications in every 15 minutes but I couldn't change the content of notification. I have a string-array and workmanager sends always the same item. For example at first it takes the valur "four" and it sends always "four"

1 - I defined a string array in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="numbers">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
    <item>four</item>
    <item>five</item>
</string-array>
```

2 - My MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public static final String KEY_TASK_DESC = "key_task_desc";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers);

    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.nextInt(list.length);

    Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putString(KEY_TASK_DESC, list[number]).build();

    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest
            .Builder(MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTE)
            .setInputData(data)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(periodicWorkRequest);

}}
```

3 - MyWorker Class containing displayNotif(String inputData) method

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    String inputData = getInputData().getString(MainActivity.KEY_TASK_DESC);
    displayNotif(inputData);

    return Result.success();
}

private void displayNotif(String inputData) {
    NotificationManager manager =
            (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notif",
                "notif", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "notif")
            .setContentText(inputData)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're perhaps misunderstanding your `PeriodicWorkRequest` setup.

You are only calling `setInputData` once, with one `data` (your string). Every time it runs, it still only has this `data`.

To randomly display a string, your random selection has to happen inside your Worker's `doWork`.